# Transitioning from Shapely in Python to SDL in C++

Tags: python, c++, sdl, collision-detection, shapely

I have some python  code that uses shapely.  I have to translate  this code to C++ and continue  the development  after that. 
However  I would like to know  if I could achieve  what's  done in shapely  using the SDL library  (I have some  experience  with SDL but not with shapely)

If someone  only uses python  the question  could be reformulated as:  coule pygame (given it's based on SDL) be used to replace basic functionalities in shapely?  and if yes what is the overlap betweeen them?

Comment: Why not just use the underlying [GEOS library](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) directly?

Comment: Because  i already  i have some  experience  with SDL and actually  I'm not sure if I can do in SDL what's  done in shapely (geos) that's  why I am asking. And at the moment i don't  know exactly  what functionalities  of shapely  are used  in the old project, thus i would  the areas of overlap  between  the two. I will have a closer  look at Geos soon